# Flutter better_player not working in Google PlayStore

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, live-video

I have a problem with better_player.
I can use better_player with emulator and real device.
But when I deploy Google PlayStore its not working.
You have an any idea?

[Its my real device working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6dWy.jpg)

But not working here
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kibris.kibris_tv

Comment: Have you added the internet permission in the release manifest?

Comment: of course,
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Is there a need to add it somewhere different? @TirthPatel

Comment: @streji have you resolved this issues?

Comment: @streji. Is this player working good in  your real device?I am also implementing a video streaming with better_player. But I am facing issues on controls of this player. will you please help?

Comment: @streji controls are not working flexibly? It's working after tapping 2,3 times on any control.

Comment: actually i fixed but I forgot write here. sorry guys.
 i think the permission was related to the written code